# Ggplot2: Changing the color for a single value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a line plot with ggplot and I want to set the color for one of the values as black and leave the rest to default. I need to create multiple line plots with this code, and only the values (here "A") stays the same across all the plots.

My problem:
I managed it somehow, but my problem now is, that the value is not beeing displayed in the legend with the others anymore. How can I make it appear there again?

```
mydata <- data.frame("Letter" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D",
"A", "B", "C", "D"), "Month" = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb",
"Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr", "Apr"), "Number" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 3,
6, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 5, 7))
```

This plot is how I would like it, but "A" is not beeing displayed in the legend.

```
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = Month, y = Number, colour = Letter, group = Letter))
+ theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank())
+ geom_line(data=subset(mydata, Letter == "A"), colour="black", size = 1)
+ geom_line(data=subset(mydata, Letter != "A"), size = 1)
+ geom_point(data=subset(mydata, Letter == "A"), colour="black", size = 1.5)
+ geom_point(data=subset(mydata, Letter != "A"), size = 1.5)
```

"A" is beeing displayed in the legend, but it's line / dots is not black.

```
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = Month, y = Number, colour = Letter, group = Letter))
+ theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank())
+ geom_line()
+ geom_point(size = 1.5)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
#show the three colors of the ggplot default
library(scales)
show_col(hue_pal()(3))

#set colors
group.colors <- c(A = "#000000", B = "#F8766D", C = "#00BA38", D = "#619CFF" )

#plot
library( ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = Month, y = Number, colour = Letter, group = Letter)) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank()) +
  geom_line( data = mydata, size = 1 ) + 
  geom_point(data = mydata, size = 1.5 ) +
  scale_colour_manual( values= group.colors )  # <-- set the chosen colors
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do it without having to define the colors of B, C and D?

Comment: @Hurlikus I beloieve you have to set them all manually.. but you could use the hue_pal-function for that.... `group.colors <- c("#000000", hue_pal()(3))`, and then name the vector `names( group.colors ) <- LETTERS[1:4]`

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example with the code above? Where would I put the 'names ...'    part?

Comment: @Hurlikus first, you create a vector of colurs, using scales::hue_pal()-function. Then, using `names`, you set the names for this vector... ggplot handles this further in the legend.`library(scales);
group.colors <- c("#000000", hue_pal()(3));
names( group.colors ) <- LETTERS[1:4];
group.colors`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!